# Is there a function to get the system path for the current language?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, uri

If I'm using multiple languages on the site with path prefixing, is there a quick way to get a system path for the current language?

For example, if the current language is English, and I'm interested getting the English path for 'user/password', what function call (or small number of lines) will return 'en/user/password'?

The following doesn't seem to work; it returns nothing:

```
drupal_lookup_path('alias', 'user/password', $language->language);
```

Comment: What's the value of `$language->language`?

Comment: If English is the current interface language, then that would be "en" as the "language" property of the global object is the language code.

Answer (score 0):

The internal path is same for all languages,though you can set different alias for different languages. From your question it seems that you want to get the path with language prefix not the alias, if so then I don't think there is any function that will return the path with language prefix.

Since you can get the language using `$language->language` you can write a custom function as follows.

```
function custom_lookup_path($action, $path = '', $path_language = NULL){
   global $language;
   if(empty($path_language)){
      $path_language=$language->language;
   }
   if(!empty($language->prefix)){
      $path = $language->prefix.'/'.drupal_lookup_path($action, $path , $path_language);
   }
   else{
      $path = drupal_lookup_path($action, $path , $path_language);
   }
   return $path
}
```

Comment: $language->prefix would be better as the language code isn't necessarily the same as the prefix.

Comment: @colan yes, you're correct